# Implement svm in opencv to classify skin cancer data

Tags: python, classification, svm

I am using svm in python. I am providing a csv file for the svm classifier with the target attributes being Benign and Malignant. How to use the classfifer to classify and give the output as either 'malignant' or 'benign' rather than the accuracy or the confusion matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `sklearn` to instantiate and train your model, you can do this easily with one line of code:

```
target_prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
```

where `clf` is your trained model and `X_test` is your feature test split `dataframe`

Comment: Thank you @Matt_Haythornthwaite